# Move captions below images in Meta Slider

Tags: css

I have this site in which I am using Meta Slider in Wordpress. I want to move the captions beneath the images, not on top of them. Meta Slider says this is a feature for Pro only, but can't you accomplish this by using the CSS to move the captions? I tried using margin-top but it didn't work. Just curious if there is an easy CSS fix to this?

```
http://66.147.242.87/~briantur/sound/
```

and this CSS:

```
.metaslider .caption,
.metaslider .cs-title,
.metaslider .nivo-caption {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: as I realized you want to hide these captions, yes?

Comment: Hi Vahid, I am just trying to move them under the images, not hide them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code:

```
metaslider .caption 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vahid, now the comments are below but in a div that is getting cut off (you can see it here, thin black bar at bottom: http://66.147.242.87/~briantur/image/). Would I need to re-code the plugin in the editor to make that div go below the images div? Thank you!

Comment: no @leahdesigns just remove this code from your css codes :.metaslider .caption {
padding: 5px 10px;
}

Comment: if your problem has been solved select this answer as correct one! thanks!

Comment: Hi Vahid, I changed it to "top: 20px;" and it worked, thank you!

Comment: with JavaScript you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2016...
Using a ftp program like Filezilla and the code editor of your choice like Bluefish -or- cPanel File Manager - Edit;

sftp to your website and Navigate here:
**public_html/** (wordpress/ ? or wherever WP is:) **/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/metaslider/** ... download, edit and upload: ***public.css***

Comment Out line 20 by adding these  /*  ...   */ to ***position: absolute;***
 Like this:

```
 /*   position: absolute;   */
```

Here's the whole section with line 20 commented out:

```
.metaslider .caption-wrap {
 /*   position: absolute;   */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

This is the Only change that you need to make and it does not break the responsive design.

Reload the page.

You may need to clear your browser's cache to see the changes.

You may also need to set the image Height larger that the images in the Meta Slider gui.

(.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=metaslider)